# How to handle this kind of printing in java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, printing

While printing, "The winner is student 1 student 2 student 4 student 5 with points 20" this is the string being printed, I instead want this, "The winner is student 5 with points 20."

If more than one scores are equals I want the output to be "The winner is student 1 student 5 with points 15."

It is a problem to calculate the points of each student based on the number of vowles.
Here is the Input given:

mango basket ball auspicious kangaroo

precaution misbehavior battery cup screen

parasite hello good come education

invitation squeeze paper ant multiplication

COOPERATION DEMOCRACY CONGRATULATIONS YOU BYE

Here is the code:

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    char vowels[]={'A','E','I','O','U'};
    String input[][]=new String[5][5];

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String ip[]=new String[5];
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        ip[i] = sc.nextLine();
        input[i]=ip[i].split(" ");
    }

    int vowel_count[][]=new int[5][5];
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
            for(int k=0;k<5;k++){
                char temp=vowels[k];
                for(int l=0;l<input[i][j].length();l++){
                    if(temp==Character.toLowerCase(input[i][j].charAt(l))||temp==Character.toUpperCase(input[i][j].charAt(l))){
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            vowel_count[i][j]=count;
            count=0;
        }
    }
    int score[] = new int[5];
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
            if(vowel_count[i][j]==1||vowel_count[i][j]==0){
                System.out.print("0\t");
                score[i]+=0;
            }
            else if(vowel_count[i][j]==2){
                System.out.print("1\t");
                score[i]+=1;
            }
            else if(vowel_count[i][j]==3){
                System.out.print("3\t");
                score[i]+=3;
            }
            else if(vowel_count[i][j]==4){
                System.out.print("4\t");
                score[i]+=4;
            }
            else if(vowel_count[i][j]==5){
                System.out.print("6\t");
                score[i]+=6;
            }
            else{
                System.out.print("8\t");
                score[i]+=8;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    int max=0;
    String max_index=new String();
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        System.out.println((i+1)+"\t"+score[i]);
        if(score[i]>max && score[i]!=0){
            max=score[i];
            max_index=max_index+"student "+String.valueOf(i+1)+" ";
        }
        else if(score[i]==max&&score[i]!=0){
            max_index=max_index+"student "+String.valueOf(i+1)+" ";
        }
    }
    if(max!=0){
        System.out.println("The winner is "+max_index+"with points "+max);

    }
    else{
        System.out.println("No one has got any points");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please provide [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You should search for all the winners first and just then start concatenating the message string. Talking about the part where you set `max_index`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove max_index from if statement otherwise it will add up every student.

```
 int max = 0;
    String max_index = new String();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println((i + 1) + "\t" + score[i]);
        if (score[i] > max && score[i] != 0) {
            max = score[i];
            max_index =  "student " + String.valueOf(i + 1) + " ";
        } else if (score[i] == max && score[i] != 0) {
            max_index = max_index + "student " + String.valueOf(i + 1) + " ";
        }
    }
```

Comment: only if two students have the same marks it will show the name of two students.

Answer (score 0):

Use a first loop to get the max

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    if(score[i]>max && score[i]!=0){
        max=score[i];
    }
}
```

Then another one to set the names

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    if(score[i]==max&&score[i]!=0){
        max_index=max_index+"student "+String.valueOf(i+1)+" ";
    }
}
```